# navigation button for second page appears on the home page

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have BottomNavigationView in my android program, and even though the buttons work properly to direct to the related page, the second page appears on top of home page.
Does anyone knows what can be the possible problem?

Comment: you should add more details to your question. what do you mean by "the second page appears on top of home page"?

Comment: I am using "BottomNavigationView", and try to connect second button in the navigationView to another layout. Problem is that it works and the second button opens the second page and layout but on top of the home page.